# onesignal api response says "This API is not available for applications on your plan.". How can I fix it?

Tags: api, axios, onesignal

I am working on creating segments calling API referring to Onesignal API docs "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps/${ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID}/segments" without using Onesignal dashboard. Following code is to do it, but the response is 'This API is not available for applications on your plan.'. How can I fix it? Is there anyone challenging it? let's share treatment of it!

```
app.get('/segment', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    await axios.post(`https://onesignal.com/api/v1/apps/${ONE_SIGNAL_APP_ID}/segments`, {
        name: 'aaaaaaaazzz',
        filters: [
            {"field": "tag", "relation": "=", "key": "chat_room_id", "value": "1111111"},
        ],
    },{
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            'Authorization': `Basic ${API_KEY}`
        }
    })
        .then((res) => {
            console.log("data = ", res.data['error']);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log(error.response.data);
        });
} catch (error ) {
    console.log(error);
}});
```

this is the detail of response of the above api
{
success: false,
errors: [ 'This API is not available for applications on your plan.' ]
}

And I have tried another way to deal with this problem. The thing is that I used "onesignal-node" library installed from NPM. It returns the same one. its code is the following.

```
app.get('/segment_library', async (req, res, next) => {
try {
    const response = await client.createSegment({
        name: 'new-segment',
        filters: [{"field": "tag", "relation": "=", "key": "chat_room_id", "value": "1111111"}]
    });
    console.log(response.body);

} catch (error ) {
    console.log(error);
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you need to upgrade to a paid account. Please look at this REST API doc as a reference:

https://documentation.onesignal.com/reference/create-segments